# Matlab- How to combine 2 arrays?

Tags: matlab

I have two arrays :

**A:** <500x1 cell>   *and*
 **B:** <500x1 single>.

**A** contains strings and **B** contains numbers.

I want to concatenate the 2 arrays to create a **<500x2>** array.
How can I do this?

Comment: [cell2mat(data1) data2]?

Comment: @Divakar that didn't help. The contents of B got disappeared in the resulting array

Comment: Your output 500X2 would be a cell array?

Comment: Yes. I need cell array as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce a 500x2 cell array:

```
[A num2cell(B)]
```